# getting error while deleting record in the table - method not allowed "405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

i want to delete record using ajax call but im getting error method not allowed. 405 error.

code

HTML

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteTrip(@item.TripId)">Delete</button>
```

> JS

```
var DeleteTrip = function (TripId) {

        var ans = confirm("Do you want to delete item with Item Id: " + TripId);

        if (ans) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/TripsReport/Delete/" + TripId,
                success: function () {
                    window.location.href = "/TripsReport/Index";
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

c# code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            tripsService.DeleteTrips(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the url be "/TripsReport/Delete?id=" + TripId,

Comment: but the debug point is not hitting to the method Delete.

Comment: Did you specify Routes?

Comment: yes i have specified routes, this is .net core . may i know where will the routes.

Comment: I also think the success part is not needed since you already have RedirectToAction() in your server code.

Comment: Did you see my edit in the first remark?

Comment: @PaulSinnema , tried ur code , same error - https://localhost:44308/TripsReport/Delete/3 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223723/discussion-between-krishna-mohan-and-paul-sinnema).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test my code,and I find HTTPDelete and HttpPost can work.

Here is a demo for HTTPDelete:

View:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteTrip(1)">Delete</button>

    @section scripts{
    
        <script>
            function DeleteTrip (TripId) {
    
                var ans = confirm("Do you want to delete item with Item Id: " + TripId);
    
                if (ans) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "DELETE",
                        url: "/TripsReport/Delete",
                        data: {
                            id: TripId
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            window.location.href = "/TripsReport/Index";
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        </script>
    }
```

controller:

```
[HttpDelete]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Here is a demo for HTTPPost:

View:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteTrip(1)">Delete</button>

    @section scripts{
    
        <script>
            function DeleteTrip (TripId) {
    
                var ans = confirm("Do you want to delete item with Item Id: " + TripId);
    
                if (ans) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/TripsReport/Delete",
                        data: {
                            id: TripId
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            window.location.href = "/TripsReport/Index";
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        </script>
    }
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have changed both ajax and controlled code to GET and HttpGet, Now its working.

```
 if (ans) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/TripsReport/Delete/" + TripId,
                    success: function () {
                    window.location.href = "/TripsReport/Index";
                }
            })
        }
```

C#

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            tripsService.DeleteTrips(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Get can be cached by the browser, so be careful. Post should work, although I can't see what the issue is myself.

Comment: Did you try a [httpDelete] command instead, maybe Post requires a body.

Comment: @RichardHubley i tried with httpDelete, its saying method not allowed

Comment: did you get a 405 error again when c# had [HttpDelete] and ajax had type = "DELETE"?

Comment: @RichardHubley. yes im getting method not allowed for httpdelete and Delete.